# How do I install the Ubuntu Software-Center in Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, repository, deb

I have been trying to install the Ubuntu Software-Center in Debian Jessie. I have attempted to install it from the version 5 deb that I found, but it runs into an error saying it can't run along with python-gi.  I don't know whether a newer version would have the same issue, or how I would go about located it.

I read that installing it with `apt-get install software-center` should work, but I don't know the repository for it.

How can I install this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the software-center and where you're trying to install it?  How does Ubuntu relate?

Comment: it's called the software-center and it's typically a staple of the ubuntu os, sometimes called the ubuntu software center

Comment: Ah, OK.  I can't offer a solution but in general, this kind of stuff is hit or miss in terms of what Ubuntu packages will work with Debian.  It is generally easier in the other direction.  As a first step, I'd do a search for reports of people having successfully done it, and see what their experience and advice is.

Comment: Gnome includes Gnome Software center .Why that didn't work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 5 months old, but someone just asked me the same thing in IRC!
AFAIK, there hasn't been a software center-type app in Debian for years...since Debian 5 or maybe even before that, I believe. But take heart, all is not lost. I'll briefly explain.

I used Ubuntu for a while, and for me the Software Center was just "okay." 
I currently use Debian Buster (upgraded from 9.2 Stretch) with Kernel 4.13.4-2 (2017-10-15) just so you know.

You don't need a "software center." Just use open a terminal and type apt show "packagename" without the quotes. You'll get info about it if the package is available for you.

If you must use a GUI, then use Synaptic. In my Cinnamon DE it's under menu > administration >Synaptic. Might be different with another DE, but if you're using Debian, you have it. Find it, run it, use the GUI and search away!

IMHO, Synaptic is FAR better than any Software Center I've ever used.
You DO need root permissions to install or remove packages (of course).

I LOVE Debian, and I have ***far*** more software available than I'll ever use!

Happy package hunting!

Comment: Thank you for answering to this even if it is 5 months old I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

go into the Synaptic Package Manager, search for "Software Center", scroll down the list till you find: Software Center for GNOME.  Mark for installation then apply.  You will now have your Software Center installed on Debian 10.5.

I am using the Cinnamon flavor GUI..  Good Luck..